# How to add firebase value in a tableview

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, uitableview

I've got a problem or more exactly a misunderstanding by myself about how to connect a table view with value on Firebase.

My informations :

I have a Firebase which one of many other folder is called "Flights". In a view of my application i can add somes informations in this folder following this path : Flights > userId > autoId > my interested values including a date and somes other String

My question is :

how can I add in a tableView, when this one is created by the viewDidLoad, one new personalised cell by each autoId in my folder Flights > userId ?

my trying :

I declare my array :

```
 var datas: [Flight] = []
```

I call on the viewDidLoad() this function :

```
func loadFlights() {
    ref = Database.database().reference()
   let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    ref.child("flights").child(userID!).childByAutoId().queryOrderedByKey().observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

        if let valueDictionary = snapshot.value as? [AnyHashable:String]
        {

            let date = valueDictionary["Date"]
            let type = valueDictionary["aircraft-model"]
            let registration = valueDictionary["aircraft-registration"]

            let totalTime = valueDictionary["TOTAL-TIME"]

            let depTime = valueDictionary["departure-time"]
            let depPlace = valueDictionary["departure-place"]

            let arrTime = valueDictionary["arrival-time"]
            let arrPlace = valueDictionary["arrival-place"]
            self.datas.append(Flight(from: date ?? "XX-XX-XX", type!, registration!, totalTime!, depTime!, depPlace ?? "NIL", arrTime!, arrPlace!))

            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }else{
            // nothing need to happens
        }
    })

}
```

finaly I have my table manager part :

```
// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return datas.count
    //return newFlight.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    // creer la cellule

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "lbCells") as! LogBookCell

    cell.dateLabel.text = datas[indexPath.row].date
    cell.typeLabel.text = datas[indexPath.row].type
    cell.RegistrationLabel.text = datas[indexPath.row].regi

    cell.totalTimeLabel.text = datas[indexPath.row].totalTime

    cell.depTimeLabel.text = datas[indexPath.row].depTime
    cell.depPlaceLabel.text = datas[indexPath.row].depPlace

    cell.arrTimeLabel.text = datas[indexPath.row].arrTime
    cell.arrPlaceLabel.text = datas[indexPath.row].arrPlace

    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete{
        datas.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

And I don't understand why nothing appear when I load the tableView page on my application ...

thanks for your help !

Flyer-74

Comment: why are u not following Firebase documentation. if u want to showing ur data in table view than no need for save individual data just save array. after that just fatch data with objective name .

Comment: Thank but I didn't find something like this in the Firebase documentations .... I've been tried to do like that ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can observe a value while add or delete.

```
var ref: DatabaseReference! = Database.database().reference()
     ref.child("devices").child(user!.uid).child("device_name").setValue("iPhone test")

let newRef = ref.child("rooms").childByAutoId()
newRef.child("name").setValue("Room test")                                   
                            ref.child("devicesrooms").child(newRef.key).child(user!.uid).setValue(true)

let ev = ref.child("devicesrooms").child(newRef.key)
    var deviceNames = [String: String]()
    var deviceHandles = [String: UInt]()

// Listen for added devices
ev.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) -> Void in
    // Retrieve device key
    let deviceKey = snapshot.key

    // Add observer on device
    var handle: UInt = 0

    handle = ref.child("devices").child(deviceKey).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        let deviceName = value?["device_name"] as? String ?? ""

        // Update or Add deviceName and handle in your dictionary
        deviceNames[deviceKey] = deviceName
        deviceHandles[deviceKey] = handle
    })
})

// Listen for removed devices
ev.observe(.childRemoved, with: { (snapshot) -> Void in
    let deviceKey = snapshot.key

    // Remove deviceName from your dictionary
    deviceNames[deviceKey] = nil

    // Retrieve handle from your dictionary
    if let handle = deviceHandles[deviceKey] {
        // Remove observer on device
        ref.child("devices").child(deviceKey).removeObserverWithHandle(handle)
    }

    // Remove handle from your dictionary
    deviceHandles[deviceKey] = nil
})
```

Comment: I've adapt the code to my project, now I'm able to find the good AutoId but and Enter in the good Object in my database but the object didn't send his Value ... In fact, in this case deviceName send the value insert : as? String ?? "HERE" because value?["device_name"] is not completed ...

Answer (score 0):

Where/ when are you setting up your table view?

```
func setUpTable() {
  tableView.delegate = self
  tableView.dataSource = self 
  registerCell(name: "yourcell")
}
```

Make sure it's before you call to `loadFlights()`